# Call Javascript from code behind after partial postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a RadTreeView in a UserControl that is in an UpdatePanel and opens in a jQuery popup window. A button within the control raises a click event that is picked up by the containing page and results in the user control adding a new node to the RadTreeView from the code behind of the user control. Once this happens I want to then call a JavaScript function (that loops through all nodes and sets their visibility based on a filter string). Ideally I want to set this script call from the same function within the user control.

I have tried the following from code behind of the user control

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
            this, 
            this.GetType(),
            "filter", 
            "filterItems('" + this.RadTV.ClientID + "','" + this.txtFilter.Text + "');", 
            true );
```

I have also tried something similar from the code behind of the parent page and registered the Script Block with the appropriate UpdatePanel.

In both cases, the Script is never called.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Stewart

Answer (score 0):

You need handler for doing this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandle);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandle);
          function beginRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
          //Do something when call begins.
          }

          function endRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
          Yourfunction();//Call your function here
          }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you enlarge on this. If I add this code to the page, how do I go about calling it on partial postback?

Comment: Do you want to call after the call completes or before the call starts.

Comment: Then call your function in  endRequestHandle() as above, replace YourFunction() with your code/function.

Comment: But when and from where does the handler get called? Sorry if these are naive questions, but am not experienced with JS handler.

Comment: Actually the handlers are registered in the first two lines with the Ajax framework. The Ajax framework on itself calls the handlers.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how to implement this. I don't want to call this function at the end of every request, only when a certain postback event occurs and I need to pass parameters to the function from the control that raises the postback.

Comment: You can get the control which raised the event var pbControl = Args.get_postBackElement(); and use if condition like if(pbControl.name.toString()=="YourButton") to prevent code form always executing.

Comment: OK, but I also need to pass in the ClientID of the RadTreeView within the control, which I only have access to from within the control itself, whihc is why I needed to call the client function from code behind in user control making the postback